# Find out the names of all the attributes in an entity returned from CRM Dynamics

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I got myself into the server and I have retrieved (hopefully) the correct set of data. Then, I tried to list all the companies by the following code.

```
EntityCollection result = proxy.RetrieveMultiple(expression);
foreach (var entity in result.Entities)
{
  String output = String.Empty;
  if (entity.Attributes.Contains("account"))
    output = entity.Attributes["account"].ToString();
}
```

However, it'd be nice to run an inner loop that goes through all the available attributes in `result.Entities`. Should I use `entity.Attributes.Keys` or is there a better method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this should do the trick.

```
foreach (Entity entity in result.Entities)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Object> attribute in entity.Attributes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(attribute.Key + ": " + attribute.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, so I was on the right track. I was afraid that the recommendation for entities gotten from Dynamics were to be handled in a different way. I also made a small change to your example.

Answer (score 0):

This carries out the task using a Lambda expression.

```
EntityCollection result = proxy.RetrieveMultiple(expression);
foreach (var entity in result.Entities)
{
    var vsHeaders = entity.Attributes.Select(kvp => string.Format("{0}", kvp.Key));
    string sHeaders = string.Join(",", vsHeaders);
}
```